# Prolog (arguments not instantiated)

Tags: list, prolog

I am writing a predicate that separates consecutive  elements(all negative or positive) into different groups
like

```
same([1,2,3,-1,-3,-2,4,5,6],X).
would output [[1,2,3],[-1,-3,-2],[4,5,6]]
```

and my code is below(only positive part):

```
same([],[]).  
same([H|T],[[X,Y,H]|Tail]):-
   X >= 0,
   H >= 0,
   same(T,[[X,Y]|Tail]).

Error message:ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _4652>=0
ERROR:    [8] sign_runs([2,2|...],[_4696,_4702|...]) at /Users/filepath:40
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Could somebody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which argument is not instantiated?.... I'm so confused...

Comment: That's impossible... I post a question on StackOverflow and no response after 25mins...

Comment: What about `0`?

Comment: 0 could be count into part of positive numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call **same([1,2,3,-1,-3,-2,4,5,6],X).** the second clause is called.
H is instancied with 1,  T with [2,3,-1,-3,-2,4,5,6].

So when  **X >= 0** is called, X is unknown.

**[EDIT]**

You must start the work from the end of the list, so we need three things, what do we do when we reach the end, what we do after, and how we reach the end of the list !

When there is only one element, it's easy :

```
same([X], [[X]]).
```

Now when we have got the start it's easysimple, we work with this configuration :

**same([H|T], [[X|T1]|Tail]).**

From **same([X], [[X]])**, T is instancied with **[]**, idem for **T1** and **Tail**.

Now we just have to check the product H*X
If it's greater than 0 we put H in the head of **[X|T1]** e.g. **[H,X|T1]**, if not we create a new list
**[[H],[X|T1]|Tail]**.

The last thing if to reach the end of the list. Recusion if our friend

```
same([H|T], Tail) :-
   same(T, Tail1),
   ...
```

Now we can write the whole code :

```
same([X],[[X]]).

same([H|T], Tail):-
    same(T, [[X| T1]|Tail1]),
    /* Bad answer for [1,2,0,-5] 
    ( H*X >= 0
    ->  Tail = [[H, X | T1] | Tail1]
    ;   Tail =  [[H], [X|T1] | Tail1]).
   */
   (   H >= 0
   ->  (X >= 0
       ->  Tail = [[H, X | T1] | Tail1]
       ;   Tail =  [[H], [X|T1] | Tail1])
   ;   (X < 0
       ->  Tail = [[H, X | T1] | Tail1]
       ;   Tail =  [[H], [X|T1] | Tail1])).
```

And we get :

```
  ?- same([1,2,3,-1,-3,-2,4,5,6],X).
X = [[1, 2, 3], [-1, -3, -2], [4, 5, 6]] ;
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, And any idea about how to solve this problem?... I still can not figure out this problem...

Comment: Actually, the output could be different as expected when 0 appears in the list because 0*-5 also >=0, and a list like [1,2,0,-5] will output [[1,2,0,-5]] rather than [[1,2,0],[-5]]. I already solved this problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that ! I edited my asnwer.