# Write a predicate to divide a list of numbers into multiple lists

Tags: prolog

Divide a list of numbers into multiple lists, each of which is the longest sequence of negative or non-negative numbers in the original list.
For example:

```
?- plus_or_minus([278,31,-3,-6,18,0,0,5,101,-45,0], RunList). 
RunList = [[278,31], [-3,-6], [18,0,0,5,101], [-45],[0]]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question to conform with the point outlined on [the tour site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: Duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194174/prolog-arguments-not-instantiated

Comment: @joel76 Sorry, I have checked it before，but that answer use ";". If I am not allowed to use ";", how can I  write the predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that disjunction is not allowed. But, when constructing the output list, a comparison must be made between the *sign* of the current integer and the next integer (if any). A portable solution without using disjunctions:

```
plus_or_minus([], []).
plus_or_minus([I| Tail1], [[I|Is]| Tail2]) :-
    integer_sign(I, Sign),
    plus_or_minus_sign(Sign, Tail1, Is, Tail2).

plus_or_minus_sign(-1, Tail1, Is, Tail2) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign_negative(Tail1, Is, Tail2).
plus_or_minus_sign(+1, Tail1, Is, Tail2) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign_positive(Tail1, Is, Tail2).

plus_or_minus_sign_negative([], [], []).
plus_or_minus_sign_negative([I| Tail1], Is, Tail2) :-
    integer_sign(I, Sign),
    plus_or_minus_sign_negative_same(Sign, I, Tail1, Is, Tail2).

plus_or_minus_sign_negative_same(-1, I, Tail1, [I| Is], Tail2) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign(-1, Tail1, Is, Tail2).
plus_or_minus_sign_negative_same(+1, I, Tail1, [], [[I| Is]| Tail2]) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign(+1, Tail1, Is, Tail2).

plus_or_minus_sign_positive([], [], []).
plus_or_minus_sign_positive([I| Tail1], Is, Tail2) :-
    integer_sign(I, Sign),
    plus_or_minus_sign_positive_same(Sign, I, Tail1, Is, Tail2).

plus_or_minus_sign_positive_same(-1, I, Tail1, [], [[I| Is]| Tail2]) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign(-1, Tail1, Is, Tail2).
plus_or_minus_sign_positive_same(+1, I, Tail1, [I| Is], Tail2) :-
    plus_or_minus_sign(+1, Tail1, Is, Tail2).

integer_sign(Integer, Sign) :-
    catch(Sign is abs(Integer)//Integer, _, Sign = 1).
```

This solution takes advantage of first-argument indexing, implemented by most prolog systems, to avoid spurious choice-points.

Sample call:

```
?- plus_or_minus([278,31,-3,-6,18,0,0,5,101,-45,0], RunList).
RunList = [[278, 31], [-3, -6], [18, 0, 0, 5, 101], [-45], [0]].
```

But is this solution, in the sense of avoiding disjunctions, worth the time to *develop* or *understand*? Doubtful. A solution using an if-then-else control construct, `->/2`, is far easier to write and understand despite being arguably less declarative.

Anyway, a single sample call or a few of them is quite limited testing. A QuickCheck implementation, such as the one provided by the Logtalk `lgtunit` tool, can help here:

```
?- lgtunit::quick_check(plus_or_minus(+list(integer), -list(types([list(negative_integer),list(non_negative_integer)])))).
% 100 random tests passed
true.

?- lgtunit::quick_check(plus_or_minus(+list(integer), -list(types([list(negative_integer),list(non_negative_integer)]))), [n(1000)]).
% 1000 random tests passed
true.
```

The `lgtunit::quick_check/1-2` predicates take a predicate type signature and an optional list of options. In this particular case, the signature specifies the first argument as an input list of integers and the second argument as a list of lists of either negative integers or non-negative integers.

Comment: How about using the evaluable functor `sign/1`? It's in ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995.

Comment: @repeat That standard function returns {-1, 0, 1}, which increases the solution code size as you need clauses to deal with the zero (that, btw, was essentially my solution before my last edit).

Answer (score 0):

You have just to modify the code this way :

```
same([X],[[X]]).

same([H|T], Tail):-
    same(T,Tail1),
    finish(H,  Tail1, Tail).

finish(H,  [[X| T1]|Tail], New_Tail):-
    H >= 0,
    X >= 0
    New_Tail = ... .

finish(H,  [[X| T1]|Tail], New_Tail):-
    H >= 0,
    ...
    ....

finish(H,  [[X| T1]|Tail], New_Tail):-
    ...
    ...
    ...

finish(H, [[X| T1]|Tail], New_Tail):-
    ... 
    ... 
    ...
```